# How can I scrape data from all pages of a website and write it to a file?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm programing a script to search for the name and the OVR of all the players from a website. When I try to do this with multiple pages and write the results to a file the output is only from the last page.

Here is the code:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

i = 0
for i in range(0, 12):
    i = i + 1
    request_result=requests.get("https://www.futwiz.com/en/fifa21/players?page=" + str(i) + "&release=icons")
    src = request_result.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(src, features="html.parser")


    results = soup.find("table", class_="table results playersearchresults")

    # Gets all the names and stores them in a file
    names = results.select('a b')
    with open("names.txt", "w+") as f:
    
        for name in names:
            data = name.get_text()
            f.write("\n")
            f.write(data)            

    # Gets all the OVR values and stores them in a file
    OVR_values = results.select('div .otherversion21-txt')
    with open("OVR.txt", "w+") as f:
        for OVR_value in OVR_values:
            data = OVR_value.get_text()
            f.write("\n")
            f.write(data)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `a+` instead of `w+` in your code. If you're using `w+`, the existing content will be overwritten by the new content. If you use `a+`, the new data will be appended to the existing content in the file.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

i = 0
for i in range(0, 12):
    i = i + 1
    request_result=requests.get("https://www.futwiz.com/en/fifa21/players?page=" + str(i) + "&release=icons")
    src = request_result.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(src, features="html.parser")


    results = soup.find("table", class_="table results playersearchresults")

    # Gets all the names and stores them in a file
    names = results.select('a b')
    with open("names.txt", "a+") as f:
    
        for name in names:
            data = name.get_text()
            f.write("\n")
            f.write(data)            

    # Gets all the OVR values and stores them in a file
    OVR_values = results.select('div .otherversion21-txt')
    with open("OVR.txt", "a+") as f:
        for OVR_value in OVR_values:
            data = OVR_value.get_text()
            f.write("\n")
            f.write(data)
```